# How to change background color in graph dynamically, into two different colors?

Tags: javascript, graph, background-color

I want to change background color of my graph into three different colors.
there are two lines in graph that is a line graph.
i want the output in the form.
1. solid light green background for whole grid.
2. from starting point of the lines till the lines meet at one point it should display red background between those lines.
3. after the point when the lines meet it should display blue background between lines.
link to what a i want in garph is:
currently i am using this as background color.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var graph = new JpGraph(
            'line',
            'graph',
            data,
            {gridBackgroundColor   : "lightgreen",}); }
```

please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For graph color,I this you should try this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#